# Test doesn't work, because my variable is always empty

Tags: c#, .net-core

I don't know why this test fails. I created a new function, tested it manually and it works fine.
After that, I attempted to create test, but it always fails.
I don't know why.
It just should clear all records from DB older than 1,5 year, but variable historyToDelete always has 0 records. There is whole test:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using TeamsAllocationManager.Contracts.EmployeeWorkingTypeHistory;
    using TeamsAllocationManager.Database;
    using TeamsAllocationManager.Domain.Models;
    using TeamsAllocationManager.Infrastructure.Handlers.EmployeeWorkingHistory;
    
    namespace TeamsAllocationManager.Tests.Handlers.EmployeeWorkingHistory
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class ClearOldEmployeeWorkingTypeHistoryRecordsHandlerTest
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
            public ClearOldEmployeeWorkingTypeHistoryRecordsHandlerTest()
            {
                DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: GetType().Name)
                    .Options;
                _context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
            }
    
            [SetUp]
            public void SetupBeforeEachTest()
            {
                _context.ClearDatabase();
    
                var employeeWorkingTypeHistory1 = new EmployeeWorkingTypeHistoryEntity 
                { 
                    EmployeeId = Guid.Parse("d6951ec1-c865-41bb-8b83-0fcd81745579"),
                    WorkspaceType = 0,
                    Created = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01)};
                var employeeWorkingTypeHistory2 = new EmployeeWorkingTypeHistoryEntity
                {
                    EmployeeId = Guid.Parse("8a6c4e1c-2c6d-4b70-a507-7bdae5f75429"),
                    WorkspaceType = 0,
                    Created = DateTime.Now
                };
    
                _context.EmployeeWorkingTypeHistory.Add(employeeWorkingTypeHistory1);
                _context.EmployeeWorkingTypeHistory.Add(employeeWorkingTypeHistory2);
    
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
    
            [Test]
            public async Task ShouldClearHistory()
            {
                // given
                int numberOfHistoryToClear = 1;
                int expectedInDatabase = _context.EmployeeWorkingTypeHistory.Count() - numberOfHistoryToClear;
                
                var command = new ClearOldEmployeeWorkingTypeHistoryRecordsCommand();
    
                var deletionDate = command.TodayDate.AddMonths(-18);
                var historyToDelete = await _context.EmployeeWorkingTypeHistory
                    .Where(ewth => deletionDate > ewth.Created)
                    .ToListAsync();
    
                var commandHandler = new ClearOldEmployeeWorkingTypeHistoryRecordsHandler(_context);
    
                // when
                bool result = await commandHandler.HandleAsync(command);
    
                // then
                Assert.IsTrue(result);
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedInDatabase, _context.EmployeeWorkingTypeHistory.Count());
                //Assert.IsFalse(_context.EmployeeWorkingTypeHistory.Any(ewth => historyToDelete.Contains(ewth.Id)));
            }
        }
        
    }
```

If I found out why it fails, I will fix whole test but  now I am stuck.

#Update 1

I found a issue. When im creating dbContext in SetupBeforeEachTest, im setting up Created to 2000.01.01. There is everything ok, but when im going out from this to the first test, when i checking up a DB i always have current date, not provided in SetupBeforeEach (2021.12.27)

Comment: The major problem here is that NUnit is for _unit tests_, but what you've written is an _integration test_. You're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Are you running tests concurrently? (which is the default in modern unit-testing frameworks as it saves considerable time on multicore systems), if so, that will probably be the culprit because your tests and logic don't look _concurrency-safe_ to me.

Comment: I wrote it based on another test that tests similar functionality and it works there, but it doesn't, and I don't see any difference.

Comment: I found an issue. Created is not getting the date from 2000, always setting up current date

Comment: But idk how to fix it

Comment: What is the value of `deletionDate` ?

Answer (score 0):

SaveChanges when creating record updating Created date, so if you want to change Created date to test in future, you need to create new record first, then save changes, update it and save changes again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the SetupBeforeEachTest() method in your ShouldClearHistory() method.